# Two method for loading html from URL?

Tags: html-agility-pack

For loading HTML from a [URL](https://videohive.net/item/inspired-slideshow/21544630), I am using the method below

```
public HtmlDocument DownloadSource(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(DownloadString(url));
        return doc;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (Task.Error == null)
            Task.Error = e;
        Task.Status = TaskStatuses.Error;
        Done = true;
        return null;
    }
}
```

but suddenly today the code above stopped working. I discovered another method and it works correctly.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url.ToString());
```

Now I just wanted to know the difference between both methods

Comment: show your `DownloadString` method

Comment: you mean this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: ah..now I see. Threre was only `doc.LoadHtml(DownloadString(url))` in your code. So I thought it is some custom method.

Comment: And what exactly stopped working? See my example, it works like a charm: https://pastebin.com/Lf8Abcnf

Comment: it gets me this error

msg: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
ie: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
src: System
 stk:    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at Time_Plus.Downloader.DownloadSource(String url) in

Comment: See my answer. So `DownloadString(url)` method throws an exception and in `catch` block you are returning `null`. And then, when you use `DownloadSource` method you receive this `null` and try to do something with it and as a result you get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems now `User-Agent` header is mandatory for [your site](https://videohive.net/item/inspired-slideshow/21544630).

Everything is fine with `HtmlAgilityPack` but you should change `DownloadString(url)` method. If you check the request using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), you will see that it returns `403 Forbidden`:

[image]

Solution is to add any `User-Agent` header to the request:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = DownloadSource("https://videohive.net/item/inspired-slideshow/21544630");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static HtmlDocument DownloadSource(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(DownloadString(url));
            return doc;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // exception handling here
        }
        return null;
    }

    static String DownloadString(String url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:x.x.x) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/x.x");
        return client.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. it's work like a charm. How can I set a proxy for user agent? is it possible?

Comment: A proxy..hmm.. what you mean by saying 'proxy'..could you please clarify?

Comment: Done by WebProxy  
`          client.Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://" + "x.x.x.x." + ":" + port), true); `